# TT vs ZZ on Twilight Fortress

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg, starcraft-terran

As TT, we were going heavy MM and rush at the 6-minute mark. However, since the map is too large, by the time we got there, they have already expanded and have enough zerlings + banelings.

What else could I have done?

Comment: Why not go for a quick Medivac or even a Viking to take advantage of his lack of anti-air?

Comment: @IvoFlipse: Zerg players tend to get good map control, besides their overlords their zerglings which are really cheap (50 for 2 = 25 for 1) allow them to do that; he will also spread creep which gives them vision. Both these thing will make him help see you coming and he will be there in no time because of the speed bonus his creep gives. Medivacs drop aren't bad, if you can avoid getting seen or catch him off-guard you'll surprise him. With Vikings you can indeed pick some overlords, but note that they defend with Queen and Spore Crawlers; and might have Hydras, Corruptors or Mutalisks.

Comment: He's talking about going in for a timed push at the 6 minute mark, you're not telling me he's got a Lair and Overlords scattered around the map yet right? If he has, an early Viking would seriously hurt the Zergs production.

Comment: You have to compare the costs in order to see... This conversation has been continued [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/conversation/ttvzz-discussion).

Comment: Did they see you coming? You might also want to try building your barracks closer to their base if you are trying to rush. Marine only might be a better choice instead of marine/marauder unless you know they are getting roaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rushes are usually most effective on small maps. On a large map your opponent has more time to prepare because it takes so long for your army to reach his base.

So on large maps it is often better to not go for a rush. Terran is good at defending, so you could have walled yourself in and defended, while getting your economy going and building up for a later but stronger push.

Answer (score 1):

On big maps I would suggest to make small pressure on opponent, to have understanding what they are doing... and expand yourself too. After that - personally I would recommend to go tech.

Once again, as sth told too: big maps are not good for early rush.

What else you could do? You MUST know that they have bannelings BEFORE you push: SCAN them or use 1 helions to see what is going on there... Once more information about their action is received try to counter that.